# OpenCV templateMatching not working properly on images with simple black and white shapes

Tags: python, opencv, template-matching

I'm using Python with OpenCV to identify specific shapes in images, but the code is incorrectly identifying the right places, resulting in false positives.

Here is the method I use to identify matches:

```
def set_markers(self):
    
        correlation_img = cv2.matchTemplate(self.base_image,self.template,cv2.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED)

        corrcopy = correlation_img.copy()

        self.markers = MarkerList(self.template)
        for i in range(0, self.markers_amount):      
            # get max value and location of max
            _, max_val, _, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(corrcopy)

            if max_val > 0.95:
                marker = Marker(max_loc[0],max_loc[1], self.template)
                self.markers.add(marker)  
                
                cv2.circle(corrcopy, (marker.x1,marker.y1), self.match_radius, 0, -1)
                i = i + 1               
            else:
                break

        if self.markers.length() != 4:
            raise Exception(f"Número de marcadores detectados difere de 4: {self.markers.length()} encontrados")
```

Note: The MarkerList and Marker classes are simply abstractions of the positions obtained from template matching. As indicated in the code, they aren't relevant to this issue. The self.template and self.base_image variables correspond to the following images:

[image][image]

While debugging, I noticed that the threshold (thresh) values of the match points are all 1.0, yet the result is still false positives. The resulting image is as follows (later in the code, I crop the area around the markers. The result is the areas inside the red rectangles, connected by the yellow line):
[image]

I've tried saving the correlation image to check the result, but it turned out to be completely black.

Notes:

I've experimented with different OpenCV methods like TM_CCORR_NORMED and TM_CCOEFF_NORMED, but didn't achieve the desired results; the threshold was set at 0.3 with more than 100 matches...

If I remove the black rectangles inside the table in the image, the code works. Here is the result:

[image]

The current approach was successful with different base images. If you check my profile, you'll see I've asked a similar question using a more complex image, and I got something close to the code I provided at the beginning of this question. For that situation, it worked perfectly. Here are the image and the result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: use `TM_SQDIFF`

Comment: TM_SQDIFF also doesn't work, I've tried all the options...

Comment: your template isn't the same size as the instances. I don't mean image size, I mean object size. `matchTemplate()` is *not* a multiscale operation. -- another approach would be "blob detection" with suitable filter for *circularity*. that'll give you the individual circles. then reassemble (group) them by center point into those markers. make sure your groupings have the expected number of circles.